# What is the smallest integer x for which you can be sure that P(n) is true for all integers n≥x?

Tags: induction

Suppose you know the following about a statement P(n).

P(3), P(5) and P(8) are all true.
P(4) is false.
For all integers k≥6, if P(k) is true then P(k+1) is true.
What is the smallest integer x for which you can be sure that P(n) is true for all integers n≥x?

So the answer that I came out with is 5 and I'm not sure that it is correct or not.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is $5$? If you include this information, people can better help you correct any misunderstandings you have.

Comment: This might be a bit weird to say but, they way i came out with my answer is that in the question it states that for all integers k>= 6 then p(k) is true then p(k+1) is also true, so if n is 5 then it will be p(6) so it will be true.

Comment: We don't know, if P(6) is true. We only know, that if P(6) is true, then P(7) is true as well.